# What is the checksum for the Hera ISO file?

Tags: system-installation, release-hera

Hera has just been released, but the installation page still has the 5.0 2018/10/16 checksum.
Can you please provide the 5.1 2019/12/02 one?
Thanks
TM

Comment: [The Support page has been updated with the new checksum.](https://elementary.io/docs/installation#choose-operating-system)

Answer (score 1):

I get:

cd66c32d53eab6f789b8e69e499305b7af0c9b3083ed54d50b111136d2795ea1

Comment: I also have cd66c32d53eab6f789b8e69e499305b7af0c9b3083ed54d50b111136d2795ea1

Comment: Where did you get it? From the file itself or from Elementary OS sources?

Comment: Anyhow, when checking I get the same you two get, so I assume it must be the correct one.

Comment: I ran the sha256sum command against the iso file.

Answer (score 0):

https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#verify-your-download

cd66c32d53eab6f789b8e69e499305b7af0c9b3083ed54d50b111136d2795ea1

Answer (score 0):

This information can be found, for each new version of elementary OS on this link

https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#recommended-system-specifications

**For version elementary OS 5.1** (subject of this conversation) you can check the ISO with this command

```
$ sha256sum elementaryos-5.1-stable.20191202.iso
```

the checksum for elementary OS 5.1 2019 12 02 should be

> cd66c32d53eab6f789b8e69e499305b7af0c9b3083ed54d50b111136d2795ea1